# Prettyphoto plugin stopped working after upgrading to jQuery 3.1.1

Tags: jquery, plugins, updates, conflict, prettyphoto

the popular modal image slider plugin, PrettyPhoto stopped working after I updated jquery library from 1.3 to 3.1.1

It would be easy to resolve the problem if the console shows any error, but it doesn't.

I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 11):

In your prettyphoto.js file, you have to replace `size()`.  That has been replaced in jquery 3.x, with `.length`.

Comment: I have been searching for a solution for the past day and this has just fixed everything

Comment: Thanks a lot. its working after replacing .size() with .length